# if use ajax call for contact form submitting, header(location:/path) not working

Tags: javascript, php

The issue is if try to ajax call for submitting my contact form. `then header("location: /path);` starts not working.

```
if ($response->success) {
      $guest = mail($serverMail, $toAdmin, $mailMessageToServer, $headers);
      $server = mail($email, $toGuest, $mailMessageToGuest, $headers);
      if (($guest) && ($server)) {
        // header("location: /contact/thankyou.html");
      } 
  } else {
    echo "Invalid captcha! Please enter again. ";
  }
```

And yes, because header redirect is not working. I comment it out. And tried to redirect page inside ajax call like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $('#mailformpro');
    var response = $('.status');
    form.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'contactform/ajax/contact.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: form.serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                response.fadeOut();
                response.fadeIn();
                response.html('Loading...');
            },
            success: function(data){
                response.html(data).fadeIn();
                window.location.href ="/contact/thankyou.html";
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log(e)
            }
        });
    });
    });
```

But this time, it's only redirecting inside the `.status` div! like in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNsTb.jpg) Normally I am displaying a error message in that div...

Comment: You don't need to use header("location: /contact/thankyou.html"); inside PHP code because you are already trying to redirect to page in JavaScript.

Comment: did you read the question? @RopAliMunshi, you giving minus you don't even read the question...

Comment: Yes I did, that's why I am suggesting you that, relocation using header() method won't work using AJAX.

Comment: Your PHP code is supposed to *only* be called from ajax, and redirecting within the PHP body means you redirect that async request - not the actual page (you make a new request to the server with ajax, not with the page you have open). You do not need `header("Location: ..");` inside the PHP, because you do it in the success of Ajax.

Comment: why bother with ajax if you are redirecting after the form is submitted? Just submit the form in the normal fashion and at the end of processing the request do the header - redirection??

Comment: okay, i didn't use `window.location.href ="/contact/thankyou.html";` at first place, but header start not working when I try to ajax. I though i must redirect page in ajax call then I insert this line `window.location.href ="/contact/thankyou.html";` and also comment out the` header` is it really that hard to understand ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey This is wrong practice if you are using ajax req then php not able to redirect to your destination all you need to redirect in ajax success response simple us

```php
$data = array();
if ($response->success) {
    $guest = mail($serverMail, $toAdmin, $mailMessageToServer, $headers);
    $server = mail($email, $toGuest, $mailMessageToGuest, $headers);
    if (($guest) && ($server)) {
        $data['status'] = 1; // for true
        $data['message'] = "your success message"; // for true
    }
} 
else {
    $data['status'] = 0; // for false
    $data['message'] = "your error message"; // for false
}
//define content type json if you never echo like echo 'ss' then no need to this
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);exit;
```

and get response in ajax request dataType Json to access json array obj

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $('#mailformpro');
  var response = $('.status');
  form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'contactform/ajax/contact.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: form.serialize(),
      beforeSend: function() {
        response.fadeOut();
        response.fadeIn();
        response.html('Loading...');
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.status == 1) {
        response.html(data.message).fadeIn();
        window.location.href = "/contact/thankyou.html";
        }
        else{
        // for error
        response.html(data.message).fadeIn();
        }
      },
      error: function(e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you for answer but now I can't even submit it.

Comment: i guess JS success part is not right, but I couldn't figure it out what s wrong there?

Comment: @parabellum if problem with jquery check console and check with alert() method on click to check submit event working or not

Comment: @parabellum please check with updated code php and js both and let me know if anything not working thanks

Comment: @parabellum i checked code code working fine now cheers good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send header as Base64 string then decode it in the service / Backend.

Comment: I am not sure how to achive that?